# Reporting Angular 2 code coverage in Jenkins - mismatch between coverage categories

Tags: angularjs, node.js, jenkins, code-coverage

We have a Jenkins build for our Angular 2 code base that is reporting on test and code coverage information in a way similar to our test and coverage reporting for our Java projects. We use Karma to generate Cobertura compatible coverage data using the following `karma.conf.js`:

```
coverageReporter: {
  dir: 'coverage/',
  reporters: [{
    type: 'html',
    dir: 'coverage'
  }, {
    type: 'lcovonly',
    subdir: 'report-lcov'
  }, {
    type: 'text-summary'
  },
  // this is the important part:
  { type: 'cobertura', subdir: '.', file: 'cobertura.xml' }
  ]
}
```

We used the `Publish Cobertura Coverage Report` plugin for Jenkins and pointed it to the `cobertura.xml` file.

The issue we're seeing is that our actual coverage seems to be a lot less than what is reported in our Jenkins UI. I believe this is because the Jenkins categories for coverage are "Packages", "Files", "Classes", "Methods", "Lines", and "Conditionals" while the categories coming from Karma are "Statements", "Branch", "Functions", "Lines". The only two of these categories that seem to be lining up is "Lines" and that's the only one that reports a coverage number other than 100%.

Is there a way to properly translate the categories from a Karma coverage report and have it displayed in Jenkins? Any solution would also be required to show a graph of the coverage history on the build summary page.

Some screenshots:

Some of our `npm test` command:

[image: npm test output]

Jenkins build summary page:

[image: jenkins build screen]

Jenkins coverage details screen:

[image: jenkins coverage details screen]

Comment: I know this is an old thread. But did you try using the preprocessor config to only use the files in your code directory?